# How can I embed both Text and Widget in another Widget in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

Given a simple example like this

```
glyphicon :: Text -> Widget
glyphicon name = toWidget [hamlet|<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-#{name}">|]

foo :: ToMarkup a => a -> Widget
foo content = toWidget [hamlet|<div class="foo">#{content}</div>|]
```

Is there a builtin mechanism in Yesod which would allow me to do both `foo "some text"` and `foo (glyphicon "pencil")`? I've managed to work around this by using a custom typeclass which converts both Text and Widget to Widget

```
class MakeWidget a where
  makeWidget :: a -> Widget

instance MakeWidget Widget where
  makeWidget = id

instance MakeWidget Text where
  makeWidget x = toWidget [hamlet|#{x}|]

glyphicon :: Text -> Widget
glyphicon name = toWidget [hamlet|<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-#{name}">|]

foo :: MakeWidget a => a -> Widget
foo content = toWidget [whamlet|<div class="foo">^{makeWidget content}</div>|]
```

but this doesn't feel right, especially since I can't even do `^{foo "hello"}` due to ambiguous types, and have to do `^{foo (T.pack "hello")}` instead.

Is there a better way of embedding both `Text` and `Widget` inside another `Widget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't go this route, specifically because of the type inference issue you already discovered. Explicitly having to call toWidget occasionally is probably the best compromise here.